# Tor Doesn't Work Anymore

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, censorship

My college uses the SonicWall firewall to block websites and unauthorized internet connections. I installed Tor 2 months ago and it worked fine. However, I'm trying to connect to the Tor Network (when I open Tor Browser in the TB folder) now and it doesn't connect. Here's the log file generated after the error says that Tor failed to establish a connection.
Can someone help me in establishing a successful connection using Tor?

EDIT: Steps I am employing.

1. I have to log in to my SonicWall firewall using a UserName and Password. Without doing this, internet connections aren't successful.
2. After logging in and gaining internet access, I start the Tor Browser.
3. The first Question: No, I don't need a proxy to connect to the Internet. My network connection is firewalled I think because whenever I try to open a website before logging in to SonicWall, I'm redirected to a login page first.
4. The second Question: Although my computer does go through a firewall, after logging in, I can use the Internet except a few sites which are blocked. HTTP, HTTPS work fine on both Chrome and Firefox.
5. Third Question: I don't know whether my ISP blocks Tor connections. When I select no, the connection window doesn't even open. When I click Yes and try to use bridges, none of them are successful.

   ```
   30-07-2014 21:25:45.132 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server. 
   30-07-2014 21:25:45.133 [WARN] connection_connect(): Bug: Tried to open a socket with DisableNetwork set. 
   30-07-2014 21:25:45.134 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (Network is unreachable [WSAENETUNREACH ]; NOROUTE; count 1; recommendation warn) 
   30-07-2014 21:30:04.557 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
   30-07-2014 21:30:04.557 [NOTICE] Pluggable transport proxy (fte exec Tor\PluggableTransports\fteproxy --managed) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched. 
   30-07-2014 21:30:04.557 [NOTICE] Pluggable transport proxy (obfs2,obfs3 exec Tor\PluggableTransports\obfsproxy managed) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched. 
   30-07-2014 21:30:04.557 [NOTICE] Pluggable transport proxy (flashproxy exec Tor\PluggableTransports\flashproxy-client --register :0 :9000) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched. 
   30-07-2014 21:30:04.558 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
   30-07-2014 21:30:05.388 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. 
   30-07-2014 21:32:06.836 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn) 
   30-07-2014 21:32:06.837 [WARN] 7 connections have failed: 
   30-07-2014 21:32:06.837 [WARN]  7 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE
   ```

Comment: I bet it is your sonic firewall, switch it off for a test with tor.Your VPN provider=your 'firewall' sees every move you do on the internet - good luck!

Answer (score 2):

U need to login in your browser!? 
I think you have a proxy web server there! If its true, try set Outbound Proxy in torrc file.

c torManual page:
https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#HTTPProxy

Answer (score -1):

In most censorship cases, the Pluggable Transport will work. You can try that and test your luck. However, remember that it is possible that you maybe uncovered. Think about that and decide the prudent action.

Comment: Using obfs3, flashproxy and fte doesn't make my connection attempt successful.

Comment: Dear, Would you provide the detail of what choices you have made before starting the Tor connection. There are three questions that you will be asked by Tor before you connect. How did you answer them?

Comment: Added in the Question